# Can anyone help me find a reason why my function, after return, changes the values of the dict I am passing?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use a copy of the decision_root dict, but my function handle_research, after return, changes the values of decision_root.

NOTE: I am not referring to decision_root anywhere in handle_research function.

```
while((len(decision_root['researches']))>0):
    research = decision_root['researches'][0].copy()
    decision_root['researches'].pop(0)
    research_chance = handle_research(research.copy(), decision_root.copy())
```

Comment: The values in `decision_root` are mutable. `dict.copy()` returns a shallow copy, not a deep copy, so the values would be aliases in both copies, and mutating the value of one in-place would change the view through the alias to the same value in the other. Short answer: Use `copy.deepcopy(decision_root)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your help in this matter.